# I haven't access to the [ScratchOrgInfo] object

Tags: scratch-org, salesforcedx-cli-auth

I have a problem with my trailhead "Quick Start: Salesforce DX".
I'm trying to do this:

```
sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a "default scratch org"
```

But become an Error: You do not have access to the [scratchorginfo] object

I make all right, step by step. Connected status is "Connected". How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

you have to enable Dev Hub in your ORG. (Setup --> DevHub)

This successfully fixed the problem for me and was able access to the [ScratchOrgInfo] object and create my Scratch Org.

See the following for more resources:

Salesforce DX Setup Guide:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_intro.htm

Specific to Dev Hub: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_enable_devhub.htm

Longer Trailhead: 'Get Started with Salesforce DX': https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-salesforce-dx?trail_id=sfdx_get_started

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/101558)

Comment: I edited the post and provided more information/resources. My solution did not require clarification from the asker, he understood. However I understand that I should include as much relevant information as I can for any other users that view this post.

Comment: If you get this error while using VSCode and sfdx, you'll want to access the tools menu (command - shift - P) and select "Authorize a Dev Hub". You then login to the org where you've enabled your Dev Hub and return to VSCode. You can then create a default scratch org

Comment: nice to the point. unlike salesforce community which starts with uninstall CLI :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. So what I did was:

1. check-in ur terminal of Visual studio code : **sfdx force:org:list --all** and see which all are authorized org and search for **D** next to it. Here D refers to as **flag for Dev Hub** and see to that you have **only one** D flag.
   [image]

2)check if you have enabled Dev hub for the D flag authorized org. If not first login to that org and go to **Setup > quick find > search for Dev Hub > Click on Dev Hub > Enable it** as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

3)Always remember that whenever you are dealing with Visual studio code and Salesforce CLI topics in trailhead, you need to authorize and login only with your newly created Trailhead Playgrounds (note: create one and use it for all the VSC topics) not with the developer account that you have.
[image]

4)Now when all this is done. You can **sfdx force:org:list --clean** to clean all the previous expired scratch orgs.
[image]

5)Now give the scratch org command **sfdx force:org:create -s -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a GeoAppScratch** and check. You will get the success message as seen below.
[image]

Please note that I have answered this as per my understanding and the way I got it to work. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please don't ask for answer acceptance, votes, or sharing on Salesforce Stack Exchange. Thank you!

Comment: Hi David, sorry about that I wasn't aware of it. My only intension was if the process helped then voting as best answer can make it available for others who are viewing instead of reading through all comments(like myself being on end-user who have searched so many things to mix and match to get to that output).